# Temperature and currency converters in OOP JS

Tags: javascript, beginner, object-oriented, unit-conversion

I just started learning OOP from Mosh on YouTube and I looked for easiest exercises to practice. Can I get a feedback on my code please? What I did wrong and what I should change?

In the code there are two exercises: the first one is a temperature converter and the second one is a currency exchange.

```
let cel = "";
let fah = "";

function Termometer(kel) {
  this.kel = kel;

  this.getCelsius = function() {
    cel = this.kel - 273;
    return cel;
  },

  this.getFahrenheit = function() {
    fah = Math.floor(cel * (9/5) + 32);
    return fah;
  },

  this.init = function() {
    this.getCelsius();
    this.getFahrenheit();
  }
}



// currency exchange
var eur = "";
var usd = "";
var gbp = "";
function Valuta(sum1, sum2, sum3) {
  this.sum1 = sum1;
  this.sum2 = sum2;
  this.sum3 = sum3;

  this.getEur = function() {
    eur = Math.floor(this.sum1 / 4.72);
  };

  this.getUsd = function() {
    usd = Math.floor(this.sum2 / 4.15);
  };

  this.getGbp = function() {
    gbp = Math.floor(this.sum3 / 5.27);
  };

  this.init = function() {
    this.getEur();
    this.getUsd();
    this.getGbp();
  }
}

var valuta = new Valuta(300, 300, 300);
valuta.init();
console.log(eur, usd, gbp)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Does this work, to the best of your knowledge? Also, please [improve the title of your question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There is an example for calling `Valuta` but there is no example for calling `Termometer`. It would also be interesting to know what the base units are for both functions.

Answer (score 1):

## 0. Little Typo

`thermometer` instead of `termometer`.

## 1. Global Variables

> ```
> let cel = "";
> let fah = "";
> ```

Variables inside a global scope can be changed from everywhere.

### 1.1 Example

Imagine `temperature.js` is your script with the global variables inside. Now someone adds a `table.js` to display tables on the html page.

```html
<script src="temperature.js"></script>
<script src="table.js"></script>
```

One line in `table.js` is `cel = "<td>...</td>"`. The author of the code has accidentally a spelling mistake and writes `cel` instead of `cell` to indicate a table cell and breaks with this line your code in `temperature.js`.

### 1.2 Quick fix

```
function Termometer(kelven) {
    this.kelven = kelven;
    this.cel;
    this.fah;

    /* ... */
}
```

With this fix we binde the variables to `Thermometer`. To access them you need to create an instance of `Thermometer`.

```
const thermometer = new Thermometer(0)
console.log(thermometer.cel)
```

This means that inside `table.js` the author needs to write explicite `thermometer.cel = ...` to break your code.

## 2. Intuitive API

> ```
> const thermometer= new Thermometer(0)
>
> thermometer.init()
>
> console.log(thermometer.getCelsius())
> console.log(thermometer.getFahrenheit())
> ```

To call `thermometer.init()` feels so wrong and it is not intuitive.

## 2.1 Quick fix

When `new Thermometer(0)` gets called, in the background a new instance gets build by the javascript runtime and it initializes all variables inside the instance.

To avoid the `init` method we can store the calculation in variables:

```
function Thermometer(kelven) {
    this.kelven = kelven;
    this.celsius = this.kelven - 273
    this.fahrenheit = Math.floor(this.celsius * (9 / 5) + 32)

    this.getCelsius = function() { return this.celsius }
    this.getFahrenheit = function() { return this.fahrenheit }
}
```

The code snipped above looks more intuitive with ES6-Classes:

```
class Thermometer {
    constructor(kelven) {
        this.kelven = kelven
        this.celsius = this.kelven - 273
        this.fahrenheit = Math.floor(this.celsius * (9 / 5) + 32)
    }

    getCelsius() { return this.celsius }
    getFahrenheit() { return this.fahrenheit }
}
```

Now, we can can interact with it like:

```
const thermometer = new Thermometer(0)

console.log(thermometer.getCelsius())
console.log(thermometer.getFahrenheit())
```

## 3. Unflexible

> ```
> function Thermometer(kel) {
>    this.kel = kel
>
>    this.getCelsius = function () {
>        cel = this.kel - 273;
>        return cel;
>    }
>
>    /* ... */
> }
> ```

Currently the Thermometer only works for `kelvin`..

It would be great to archive that we can pass in `celcius` and it still works!

### 3.1 Common Interface

That this works all Units needs to share a common api that gets called by `Thermometer`. The `Thermometer` could call methods or properties like `inCelcius`, `inFahrenheit` and `inKelvin`.

```
function Thermometer(temperature) {
    this.getCelsius = function () { return temperature.inCelsius }
    this.getFahrenheit = function () { return temperature.inFahrenheit }
    this.getKelvin = function () { return temperature.inKelvin }
}
```

Based on that we can create our units:

```
function Kelvin(value) {
    this.inKelvin = value
    this.inCelsius = value - 273
    this.inFahrenheit = Math.floor(this.inCelsius * (9 / 5) + 32)
}

function Fahrenheit(value) {
    this.inKelvin = Math.floor((value + 459) * (9 / 5))
    this.inCelsius = Math.floor((value - 32) / (9 / 5))
    this.inFahrenheit = value
}

function Celsius(value) {
    this.inKelvin = value + 273
    this.inCelsius = value
    this.inFahrenheit = Math.floor(value * (9 / 5) + 32)
}
```

Now the `Thermometer` works for all units:

```
const kelvinMeter = new Thermometer(new Kelvin(0))
const fahrenMeter = new Thermometer(new Fahrenheit(0))
const celsiMeter = new Thermometer(new Celsius(0))
```

## 4. Unexpected Behavior

> ```
> this.getEur = function() {
>    eur = Math.floor(this.sum1 / 4.72);
> }
> ```

When I would call `valuta.getEur()` I would expect that the method `getEur` returns a value. Instead it returns `undefined` and changes a global variable.

```
const valuta = new Valuta(1, 2, 3)
const euro = valuta.getEur() // undefined
```